# Subtraction between static unsigned long variables

Tags: c

I have a problem with a subtraction between two static unsigned long variables.

My variables are defined as follows:

```
static unsigned long actual_value;
static unsigned long incoming;
static unsigned long outgoing;
```

The operation I do in a while cycle is:

```
actual_value = actual_value - (outgoing - incoming) / 1000;
```

where "outgoing" is always > than "incoming".
The problem is that my actual_value doesn't change at each iteration.
I never modify the value of "actual_value" in any other point of the while cycle, so the problem is here.

In fact, if I try substituting that equation with:

```
actual_value = actual_value - 1;
```

correctly at each iteration the value decreases by 1.

However, if I change it with:

```
actual_value = actual_value - 0.1;
```

again at each iteration the value decreases by 1.
So I think I have not completely understand how static unsigned variables work.

Where's the problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is `outgoing - incoming` less than `1000`?

Comment: yes. it's a small unsigned long value (always lower than few tens).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your response yo my comment - as `outgoing - incoming` is less than `1000`, the result of `(outgoing - incoming) / 1000` will always be 0.

The solution depends on what you need. If you want to get a real value from the division, then do this:

```
( outgoing - incoming ) / 1000.0
```

which is the same as

```
( outgoing - incoming ) / 1000.
```

then you would get a floating point number, between 0 and 1.

But what do you want to achieve? If `( outgoing - incoming )` is always `< 1000` and not `0`, this code will always decrease the value of `actual_value` by `1`, as `actual_value` is `unsigned long`. If and only if `outgoing - incoming` is 0, then the `actual_value` will not be changed. Is this what you need?

---

Based on the comments below, you need a `float` or `double` type for `actual_value`. And then, use `actual_value -= ( outgoing - incoming ) / 1000.;`

If you want to print the nearest integer value to `actual_value`, you need

```
printf( "%ul\n", (unsigned long)( actual_value + .5 ) );
```

Comment: actual_value should print the nearest integer of the subtraction between its current value and another small value like 0.02, 0.043 and so on.

Comment: @user2053842 What do you mean by "the nearest integer"? Because `actual_value = actual_value - 0.043` would be the same as `actual_value = actual_value - 1` in this case.

Comment: my `actual_value` starts from 5000. If at the first iteration I subtract 0.05 to it, its value will be 4999.95, so I want it prints 5000. Only when its value will reach 4999.49 I want it prints 4999.
So should I define `actual_value` as double or float variable?

Comment: @user2053842 `actual_value` **cannot** store values like `4999.95` and `4999.49`, as it's `unsigned int`. This means integer.. You need to use `float` or `double` instead. And where do you print the value?

Comment: Immediately after the operation, with a `printf("%lu\n", actual_value);`.
Ok thanks, I didn't know that unsigned long automatically implies `int`.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If `(outgoing - incoming)` is less than 1000, then you are subtracting `0` each time, as `(outgoing - incoming) / 1000` will evaluate to `0`.

Answer (score 1):

You can forget about the `static`, that doesn't affect result of arithmetic at all, it merely deals with the variable's storage details.

This sounds as a problem with integer arithmetic being ... well integer, to me.

Decreasing by 0.1 works since that causes the rounding to work in your favor (incrementing would not work).

But your expression `(outgoing - incoming) / 1000` is *integer*, and probably evalutating to 0.

Also, you should write the first expression like so:

```
actual_value -= (outgoing - incoming) / 1000;
```

it is much more clear. Of course, this would also be trivial to debug with a debugger to see what's happening.